# aws data transfer out beyond global free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, data-transfer

I am going through  the aws bill as attached.

There is one line "aws data transfer out beyond the global free tier".
What does this statement means

1) Is this data transfer out from EC2? 
or
2) Is this data transfer out from S3?

Any help is appreciated?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Bill Details** in your screenshot are a high-level summary of your AWS costs.

To obtain more detail, turn on [Detailed Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html#other-reports). They will give full detail of every charge, such as:

```
AWSDataTransfer,AWS Data Transfer,APS1-APN1-AWS-Out-Bytes,,913894,$0.09 per GB - Asia Pacific (Singapore) data transfer to Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
```

The detail include which service trigger your data transfer costs.

You can even create a **Detailed billing report with resources and tags**, which will break-down costs based upon nominated tags. This is great for apportioning costs by Department, Cost Centre or Project.

However, the extra level of detail is only available *after* you activate Detailed Billing. It will not break-down past (historical) bills.

Comment: The Detailed Billing Report feature is unavailable for new customers as of 07/08/2019.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/detailed-billing.html#other-reports

Answer (score 3):

This is aggregate both EC2 and S3 data transfer to Internet pricing (EC2 and S3 use the same data transfer terms and conditions).

Apparently, you just jump into AWS data transfer traps, please read through : [AWS data transfer costs: What they are and how to minimize them](https://blog.cloudability.com/aws-data-transfer-costs-what-they-are-and-how-to-minimize-them/).

If you are not careful, AWS may cost you 10 times more than buying services from co-location or VPS services.

Bare in mind that, if you backup data from AWS to your intranet, that will count as "AWS data transfer to internet".  Consider backup to S3 or to another region.

Here is some [lesson to learn before switching to AWS](https://www.hivelocity.net/blog/AWS-bandwidth-expensive/) .

Answer (score 0):

It is an aggregate of all outgoing data charges, be it from EC2 or S3 or SQS.
For more details on price calculations refer the online price calculator/estimator provided by AWS at following URL 
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: is there any way I can get the separate details ?

Comment: Not sure if they provide that split up